# Returning 403 from Middleware .net Core - Creating a reverse proxy

Tags: .net, .net-core, reverse-proxy, asp.net-core-middleware

I am writing a reverse proxy using Yarp. The basic functionality works well. I have a requirement to validate some header values. I am thinking to write a Middleware and return 403 , if it does not pass. Is this a good pattern.

There is NO error coming in my middleware either. I have just not return the RequestDelegate. But i am just looking for opinions .

```
public class ValidateJwtRolesMiddleware
    {

        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

        public ValidateJwtRolesMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _next = next;
            _configuration = configuration;
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
        {
            var token = context.Request.Headers["Authorization"].FirstOrDefault()?.Split(" ").Last();

            if (token != null )
            {
                if (this.IsTokenValid(context, token))
                {
                    context.Response.Headers.Add("NEWVALUE", "TEST");
                    await _next(context);
                } else {
                      context.Response.StatusCode = 403;
                }

            }
                


        }
```

Comment: Looks good to me.  I don't like passing `IConfiguration`, though.  You should just consume the options you need using the Options pattern, i. e. `IOptions<>`.  Also I think I would do `context.Response = new ForbidObjectResult()`.  Cannot tell you why for sure. Just sounds better in my head for some reason.

Comment: thanks. Sorry the Iconfiguration, i copied from my code base, i do some role and key reading from appsettings.